# ipython notebook showing In [ ]

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, heavy-computation

In the python notebook , after an expensive computation is done I get the following output :

```
In [ ]:redas=heavytask(g,l=False)
```

instead of In [45 ]: i.e with a line number.

Earlier it showed In [ * ] then after refreshing the notebook it changed to In [ ].

I see my computation is still progressing but taking way to long (2-3) days and has become very slow. So should I continue with this ? This is a common problem that happens with ipython. Also the color rendering is lost when this happens. Although works well once you interrupt the kernel.